# Will an axial compressor work with an ideal fluid?

Tags: aerodynamics, engine, compressor

Will an axial compressor, like the one described starting on page 275 of [*Mechanics and Thermodyanmics*](https://soaneemrana.org/onewebmedia/MECHANICS%20AND%20THERMODYNAMICS1.pdf) (PDF link), work if the flow was assumed to be ideal (i.e. incompressible and inviscid)?

Specifically, what mechanism will slow the flow down in the axial direction? It's my understanding that slowing the flow down is the job of the stators, but I fail to see how they accomplish this in the axial direction.  The author states on page 284 that the axial flow velocity through the compressor is made constant by design but never explains how that design is achieved and I'm curious if that design could still be achieved with an incompressible fluid. -Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking mathematically or physically?

Comment: I'm wondering what a _compressor_ might do with an _incompressible_ fluid?

Comment: @JZYL, I think I'm looking for more of a physical explanation based on the math (i.e. an incompressible fluid is not physically possible so the mathematical assumptions must be considered)

Comment: @Haukinger, haha I see the seeming paradox, you cannot compress a fluid by increasing it's density (because it's incompressible), but you can increase it's pressure. I guess my question is trying to determine whether a compressor would work on a fluid like water (essentially incompressible).

Comment: Yes, you can axially compress water: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial-flow_pump

Comment: @JZYL, the rotor blades will create downwash in the radial and axial direction. The radial component is removed ("diffused") by the stators. What removes the axial component? Maybe conservation of mass handles this naturally...?

Comment: (Figure 7.7) The angle of the blades gets steeper across the direction of flow (beta angle). The fluid travels slower and slower as it goes through the blade due to this steeping angle (velocity w). Remember velocity of the fluid is not parallel to the axis but perpendicular to the velocity of the blade (c is constant but w isn't). You should read this chapter thoroughly.

Comment: @user3528438, thank you for the comment. If you look at Figure 7.8, you can see that the axial flow velocity ($c_z$) is assumed to be constant (at least pictorially), and is therefore assumed to not slow down. Also, I'm not understanding why your saying c is constant as $c_1\ne c_2$.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, incompressible flow is subsonic, however subsonic flows are not all incompressible. An ideal gas flow may be "incompressible" until it meets the compressor. Even if the vehicle is travelling at supersonic speed, the flow is reduced to subsonic ("incompressible") flow by the intake system before reaching the compressor. At this point the subsonic flow gets compressed. Presumably this is what is meant here.

The compressor stages each reduce the cross-sectional area, while the fans draw the gas backwards to maintain velocity. Thus the gas, ideal or not, must compress to fit the reduced volume available to it. This compression creates heat which raises the gas temperature, further raising its pressure.

Viscosity is necessary to establish a circulatory flow component around each airfoil-shaped blade (the Kutta condition). It is this circulatory component which creates the velocity differentials needed for the Bernoulli principle to create the dynamic pressure differentials which make the blades do their work. Superfluid helium (close to absolute zero) has no viscosity and has been found to exert neither lift nor drag on an immersed body.

Comment: Incompressible flow is subsonic. Subsonic flows are not all incompressible...